# Fails to get Consul Key using spring-cloud-consul

Tags: spring-cloud-consul

I am trying to get a value from Consul KV store using spring-cloud-consul

Key exist:
curl http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/config/HelloWorldClient/testKey
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"config/HelloWorldClient/testKey","Flags":0,"Value":"Y29uc3VsVGVzdEtleQ==","CreateIndex":2748497,"ModifyIndex":2748497}]

This is my bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: HelloWorldClient
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        enabled: true
        format: YAML
        prefix: config
        default-context: apps
        fail-fast: true
        data-key: data
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      enabled: true
```

Sample controller:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Controller
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PropertySourceBootstrapProperties.class)
public class ConsulValuesGetter {

    @Value("${testKey}")
    String testKeyValue;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @GetMapping("/getKey")
    public String helloClient() {

        System.out.println("Test KEY= " + null + "ENV: " +  env.toString());
        return env.toString();
    }
}
```

I am getting error: Error creating bean with name 'consulValuesGetter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'testKey' in value "${testKey}"

I see this entry:
Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='consul', propertySources=[ConsulPropertySource [name='config/HelloWorldClient/'], ConsulPropertySource [name='config/application/']]]

Maven has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
     </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Please help to resolve this problem.
Thank you.